# How to set up a chrome extension using React and TypeScript with multiple pages and entry points?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, google-chrome-extension, create-react-app

There are plenty of questions and tutorials on this topic, but none of them cover all use cases for a chrome extension, because most of them assume there's only one entry point.

Here are the requisites:

**Multiple "single page applications":**

1) `popup.html` for the extension pop up page

2) `options.html` for the options page

3) `custom.html` this is a custom `.html` file that the extension can refer to "locally"

Each of these files are entry points for React to manipulate the DOM, but they behave independently of each other.

**Non React TypeScript files**

They must not be bundled together with any other scripts, and gets compiled to its own JavaScript file, for example a `background.ts` that compiles to `background.js` (which is refered to in the `manifest.json`).

I assume this is doable with TypeScript, React and Webpack but I'm not sure how to approach that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution but it was not using `create-react-app` and `webpack`. It looks like [parcel](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel) supports multiple entry points out of the box without any configuration.

Assuming a directory structure like this:

```
├── chrome
│   └── background.ts
├── html
│   ├── custom.html
│   ├── options.html
│   └── popup.html
├── manifest.json
├── package.json
├── react
│   ├── custom.tsx
│   ├── options.tsx
│   └── popup.tsx
```

With Parcel.js you simply do:

```
parcel build html/*.html react/*.tsx chrome/*.ts
```

And it will handle the multiple entry points. I created a [repository](https://github.com/marlonguimaraes/ts-react-chrome-extension) that contains a template for that approach, it contains a fully runnable example.

Answer (score 5):

There is a custom CRA template that exactly fits your needs: [`complex-browserext-typescript`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cra-template-complex-browserext-typescript).

Usage:

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template complex-browserext-typescript
```

By default it sets up 4 entry points associated with page-like extension components:

- popup (`src/index.tsx`) - extension's popup page, replaces the
  default index entry point.
- options (`src/options.tsx`) - extension's options page.
- background (`src/background.ts`) - background script.
- content (`src/content.ts`) - content script.

However there is an option to exclude any of the above components except the popup from compilation as well as add extra HTML page(s).

Also see [this article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-build-a-rich-chrome-extension-quickly-with-create-react-app-and-redux-d9b64cf64832) for usage example.

Answer (score 0):

I build a two page chrome extension template using react in [this github repo](https://github.com/AbdelrahmanTorki/react-chrome-extension-template) for anyone who wants to get started building chrome extensions using react. The two pages represents the popup page and home or settings page.

I didn't try it with Typescript, yet, but I think normal integration of typescript with react would work as in [this guide](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/). Feel free to make a pull request adding how to integrate typescript in the readme.

If you want to add even more pages, you will need to modify some files in the `config` folder, if you want I will add the necessary steps. I may later add a function that can automate the configuration process of adding additional HTML pages for react application, but generally for extensions, two pages (popup and setting or home page) are more than enough.