# Chrome extension - run HTML file from different folder

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, directory

I am making a chrome extension, and am using React for the options page and extension popup page (the one you see when you click on an extension).

My file structure is pictured below

[image: File structure]

In the future `pages` will contain an additional `popup` folder with an entirely separate react app. This is the only way I can think of to have two separate react pages in my extension.

My `manifest.json` (the one on the top level, used by the chrome API) looks like this (irrelevant content ommitted)

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "options_page": "./pages/options/build/index.html",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ]

}
```

As you see, I render the options page from the static build files generated when the react app is built.

However, this causes the `index.html` file to be run from the top level directory (the same one as manifest.json), which results in it being unable to reference the `static` folder, `favicon.ico` etc.

How do I resolve this? Is there any way to force chrome to run index.html within the build folder? I do not want to move all items in the build folder to the top level directory as this would a) clutter up the workspace and b) cause issues when I create the second react app for the popup page and would have to do the same thing

Comment: Try [How to set up a chrome extension using React and TypeScript with multiple pages and entry points?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62186043)